# How to do exact one-to-one match validation with pydantic model schema?

Tags: python, pytest, pydantic

How can I exactly match the Pydantic schema?

The suggested method is to attempt a dictionary conversion to the Pydantic model but that's not a one-one match.

I am using something similar for API response schema validation using pytest.

```python
class Model_actual(BaseModel):
   val1 : str

dict_to_be_validated = {'val1':'Hello', 'val2':'World'}
   
assert Model_actual(**dict_to_be_validated) is not None
```

I am looking for this assertion to fail instead of pass because it this is not a one-to-one match.

Comment: Do you want the validation to fail because `Model_actual` does _not_ have `val2`? Also, pydantic validation error will raise an Exception, it will not return None. Why is the assertion `is not None`?

Comment: Yes. I'm using it in pytest. It's to ensure that no additional information is sent to the client than what they actually need.

Answer (score 4):

By default, pydantic `BaseModel`'s *ignores* extra fields (`val2` in this case).

You can tell the model to *forbid* extra fields and raise a `ValidationError` by setting the `BaseModel`'s [Model Config `extra` option](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options).

```
class Model_actual(BaseModel):
    val1: str

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"
```

> `extra`
>
> whether to ignore, allow, or forbid extra attributes during model initialization. Accepts the string values of `'ignore'`, `'allow'`, or `'forbid'`, or values of the `Extra` enum (default: `Extra.ignore`). `'forbid'` will cause validation to fail if extra attributes are included, `'ignore'` will silently ignore any extra attributes, and `'allow'` will assign the attributes to the model.

```
In [1]: from pydantic import BaseModel
   ...: 
   ...: class Model_actual(BaseModel):
   ...:     val1: str
   ...: 
   ...:     class Config:
   ...:         extra = "forbid"
   ...: 

In [2]: dict_to_be_validated = {"val1": "Hello", "val2": "World"}

In [3]: Model_actual(**dict_to_be_validated)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Model_actual(**dict_to_be_validated)

File ~/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Model_actual
val2
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

To catch that in a pytest test function, you let the test [assert that an Exception is raised](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions).

```
def test_model_ok():
    dict_to_be_validated = {"val1": "Hello"}

    obj = Model_actual(**dict_to_be_validated)
    assert obj.val1 == "Hello"

def test_model_ng():
    dict_to_be_validated = {"val1": "Hello", "val2": "World"}

    with pytest.raises(ValidationError) as exc:
        Model_actual(**dict_to_be_validated)

    assert exc.value.errors()[0]["msg"] == "extra fields not permitted"
```